# Looking for a short story about an anonymous candidate running for President

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, pulp

Way back in one of the pulp science fiction magazines (probably If or Galaxy circa 1950-1970 but could have been a more obscure one), there was this short story about someone running for President.  The story was told through a series of memoranda between the candidate and the advertising firm.   The basic plot was that they'd only refer to the candidate as "The Candidate" both in the ads and on the ballot. I remember at one point they were copying popular commercials, one about a football team that led to a teamwork themed slogan. Several ordinary-looking people - one was an old woman - were selected by the advertising firm to speak for the candidate. There was also a faked assassination attempt to "explain" why the candidate remained anonymous.

Although it's old news now, the idea of the media fabricating a candidate and controlling a major election was science fiction when the story was written/published.

Any idea what story this was or who the author was?

Comment: Was there a sci-fi/fantasy angle or element to the story? The description you wrote doesn't make it sound like there is. If not, this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: A non-entity running for President? Are you sure you weren't watching the news?

Comment: I have serious concerns about the election system in this world, where apparently just having the same name as an elected official allows you to take their place. I guess if I had changed my name to "Barack Obama" back in 2008, I'd be President now.

Comment: @KSmarts Watch *The Distinguished Gentleman* with Eddie Murphy, where he plays a conman who fudges his name to match the name of a congressman who just died and is elected solely on name recognition - never even showing his face during the campaign.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain any sci-fi or fantasy elements as currently written.

Comment: @phantom42 - there was also the episode of Lois & Clark where Tempus ran for President with his entire campaign being "Vote for XXX - he's a nice guy."

Comment: Well, better than most American election campaigns which boil down to "Don't vote for the other guy; he's a jerk."

Comment: @phantom42 You mean, "Don't vote for the other guy, he's a (communist|fascist|secret Muslim) who hates (the poor|seniors|soldiers|small businesses|the middle class|innovation|freedom|America)"

Comment: It was definitely in one of the scifi pulp magazines.  That's why I was asking the question here.

Comment: I know this story but I can't - Argh! get it off the tip of my tongue. I think it was by... Vonnegut? Philip K Dick? Ellison? The science-fiction element was the idea of a totally media-driven election. Well, it was science fiction at the time.

Comment: @Jistanidiot: I think you have the ending twist wrong. IIRC, there were several average-looking people selected by the advertising firm to stand in for the candidate, and in the end they, together, take the job.

Comment: I've identified the story, and it _was_ published in some SF-oriented books. Could someone reopen this?

Comment: Saw the edit but not voting to reopen.  Unless some additional details can be offered, don't see this as 'sci-fi' regardless of what it was published in.  One definition is "fiction dealing principally with the impact of actual or imagined science on society or individuals or having a scientific factor as an essential orienting component".  What element of that is there ?  Fiction yes, sci-fi, nope. @Kenster if you've id'd the story, can you provide anything  that support it being sci-fi (other than the mag it was published in) ?

Comment: @Stan: The story is about the impact of mass media (technology) on society, particularly politics. It still works as science fiction today, since it concerns a totally fictitious political candidate created solely by a media firm.

Comment: @Stan: At least, I *hope* it's totally fictional.

Comment: My copy of the book is packed away right now. As I recall, the SF element is probably a [20 minutes into the future](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwentyMinutesIntoTheFuture) extrapolation of media's ability to influence public opinion. I'll add the story has an ISFDB entry, and refer to #1 and #5 at http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/344/4318.

Comment: @Stan so I guess if someone asked about a story by a possibly famous author written circa 1870 about this vehicle that could travel underwater and went around the globe, that it would also be off topic since that description doesn't contain any sci-fi or fantasy elements.

Comment: @Jistanidiot Let me clarify.  In your example, there's a scientific element (unknown at the time) and the story then deals with it's impact.  That's sci-fi.  The story described above (and even the answer below) doesn't contain anything that I recognize (this is an opinion) as sci-fi.  Folks have been manipulating audiences through media for ages.  Look at it this way.  If a novel written in the 1920's talked about media manipulation through newspapers and radio, that would be straight fiction but not sci-fi (IMHO).

Comment: @Jistanidiot Another novel authored at the same time also discussed such media manipulation but did it in the context of new media methodologies unknown at the time (internet for ex), I would classify that one as sci-fi.

Comment: @Stan: I think this is getting into the old debate of hard-science SF vs. soft-science SF. The rules of this site are written to be inclusive of both forms, with a lot of  wiggle-room. If you have a strict hard-science-only view of science fiction, you won't be happy here.

Comment: @JoeL. Been here for 3+ years and pretty happy.  This is just one particular question that I have to disagree on.  I'm simply unable to see even the 'soft' sci-fi in it.  Not a problem.  I spoke my peace, let the community rule :)

Comment: The thing that prompted me to ask this question was an episode of _Black Mirror_ called "The Waldo Moment" where a blue cartoon bear named Waldo runs for elective office and the person who did the cartoon is eventually replaced my a more sinister group of people.  The idea is obviously alive and well (or at least being recycled) in current science fiction.  This certainly wasn't like the welcome I've received from other stackexchange sites.  Thanks to everyone who helped find the answer.

Comment: @Jistanidiot don't be put off. We often get into (sometimes heated) debates here about miniscule little things. It's all part of the culture - put a dozen Star Trek geeks in a room and ask them to define the pros and cons of transporter technology. After that, you better step back against the wall and watch out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you're looking for "[The People's Choice](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?190223)" by William John Watkins. According to [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?190223), it was first published in 1974 in a pulp magazine called [Worlds of If](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?255032). In 1980 it was republished in *[Space Mail Volume II](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31416)*, an anthology which focused on SF stories written in the form of letters, journals, and the like.

The best description of the story that I could find online is part of a review of *Space Mail II* [here](http://vintage45.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/space-mail-volume-ii-edited-by-isaac-asimov-martin-harry-greenberg-and-charles-g-waugh/):

> An ad man is given a challenge. Given unlimited funds, can he make a short, fat, ugly woman President of the United States. Throughout the campaign the candidate is never seen. The slogan is “Vote For The Candidate Nobody Knows.” Looks like it’s working.

Like you said, the ad man builds a campaign where the candidate is never identified. Instead, a group of everyday, salt-of-the-earth types are featured with the idea that the candidate could be any of them.

> The campaign is hugely successful, and the candidate wins. The campaign manager is faced with the prospect of finally having to reveal the candidate to the nation. There's an assassination attempt--I don't remember if it was real or not--and it's announced the candidate would never reveal her identity and would hold office anonymously.

The [June 1974 issue of Worlds of IF](https://archive.org/details/1974-06_IF) is freely available on the Internet Archive; "The People's Choice" starts at page 143.

Comment: That sounds like the correct story.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  I'm going to try and find a copy of it now.  I definitely had that specific issue of "Worlds of If" as I remember the cover.  Thanks!